# Extract strings as an array from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
make -j128
```

i need to extract **-j128** from that string.

Now why i need array of strings as output, I have situation where i will get string as

```
repo sync -j32 && make -j128
```

In this case i need to get **-j32** and **-j128**

So the output for first case will be **[-j128]** and second case will be **[-j32,-j128]**

And final result i want is the numbers without -j that is **[128]** and **[32,128]**  which i can handle by removing -j at the front. If you guys think why cant i just extract the numbers at the beginning itself. There is  a reason for it, As the string can be like this also

```
repo blah blah 123 blah -j32 blah 3 blah
```

Where i need only **32** which starts with **-j**

I dint find a solution for this even after lots of googling may be because am not so go in regex any help will be appreciated, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does the numbers always start with - and are they the only things starting with - ?

Comment: Yes it will always starts with -j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression to match all numbers with a prefix of `-j`:

```
/-j(\d+)/g
```

And then use `.exec` to get all the groups matched and put them into an array.

See working example below:

```js
const str = "repo sync -j32 && make -j128";
let nums = [];
let regex = /-j(\d+)/g;
while(match = regex.exec(str)) {
  nums.push(+match[1]);
}
console.log(nums);
```

Comment: I think this solution is better as its working fine even if the string is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution using [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
const s = 'repo sync -j32 && make -j128';
const re = /-j\d+/g

const result1 = s.match(re);
const result2 = result1.map(x => +x.replace(/\D/g, ''));

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Here,

- `result1` will be an array of all substrings that start with `-j` followed by any number of digits.
- `result2` is the same array with all the non-digits removed, and the values converted to numbers.

Comment: Yep it works fine, Thanks for your time brother @Robby Cornelissen.